# Angular JS ui-select directive

Tags: angularjs, ui-select

I am using an angular [ui-select](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select) to show a list of potential addresses a user can go through.

When a user enters a search term into the input field, the search term itself should be highlighted in the available addresses which are shown below the input field.

The highlighting works. However, I want to be able to highlight each word of the search term by its own.

e.g. search term = "station zürich" => In this case I want that "station" is highlighted and "zürich". The highlighting should be indifferent in which order a user enters the input.

e.g. search term "station zürich" and "zürich station" should lead to the same result.

```
<div class="row-fluid sam-form-row">
            <ui-select class="span5" ng-model="selectedAddress" theme="select2" append-to-body="true" on-select="getAddressDetails($select)">
                <ui-select-match placeholder="Select or search a country in the list...">
                    <span ng-bind="$select.selected.label"></span>
                </ui-select-match>
                <ui-select-choices repeat="address in availableAddresses track by address.uniqueAddressId" refresh="onAddressSelected($select)">
                    <div ng-bind-html="address.label | highlight: $select.search"></div>
                </ui-select-choices>
            </ui-select>
        </div>
```

Any ideas how I might be able to achieve that?

Comment: You might need to create your own directive for that purpose.